# Facebook Request.newMyFriendsRequest doesn't return

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am retrieving list of facebook friends of logged in user in my main activity using Request.newMyFriendsRequest(...).execteAsync() in onSessionStateChange() callback as follows:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSessionStateChange called");
    if(session.isOpened()){
        Log.d(TAG, "session is open");
        Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new GraphUserListCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response){
                Log.i(TAG, "request completed...");

                // traverse the list
                }
        }). executeAsync();
    }
}
```

The callback is called each time the activity starts as desired. When I start the app, request completes successfully, but when I jump to another activity and come back, the request doesn't return even if callback is called and session is open as shown in following log :

```
03-22 14:56:36.603: D/ContactsFragment(32600): onSessionStateChange called
03-22 14:56:36.603: D/ContactsFragment(32600): session is opened
03-22 14:56:36.623: I/MaliEGL(32600): [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
03-22 14:56:36.623: I/MaliEGL(32600): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
03-22 14:56:36.623: I/MaliEGL(32600): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
```

It gets stuck after printing above logs. However, if I close the app, clear the recent apps and start the app again, the request is successfully completed but same problem occurs again.

I googled about this issue but found nothing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check what error do you get the next time using response.getError()?

Comment: @Fahim : I logged response.getError() but it returns nothing after printing "session is open"

Comment: Is this happening on all devices? what SDK version are you using? is this specific to this method? (e.g. does it work for `newMeRequest` for example?). If this is happening to more than one method, then probably it's something to do with your implementation. Have you tried this on a new project with nothing but your call in it?